# Applescript dictionary missing fields how to iterate over settings set

Tags: dictionary, applescript, field, keyword

In my previous question I asked how to change an AppleScript current settings to have the `ShowActiveProcessArgumentsInTitle` for the terminal profile. Because you can apply that plist field from another settings set yet the keywords in AppleScript are missing. This is proved by setting the terminal to a different profile red sands with that option toggled off using the current setting of that tab.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set newTab to do script "bash /Users/jredfox/Desktop/hello.sh"
    set current settings of newTab to settings set "Red Sands"
end tell
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
read -p "Press ENTER to continue..."
exit
```

I have `current settings of xtab` and from there I want to iterate over every field in there. How can I do this? The AppleScript dictionary I just proved is missing a field that can be applied from AppleScript but isn't in the dictionary from the script editor app. So how do I iterate every field from current settings which is a `settings set` object. There appears to be new fields which are not in the dictionary. It's not iterable so using a repeat list isn't an option.

Comment: Maybe you should link to your previous question so people have an idea what you're on about ?

Comment: I reiterated the full precious questions issue here and explained why I need to iterate over fields in an object. Because I proved it's missing in the dictionary

Comment: The settings exposed to and available in AppleScript do not have to be, and are almost never, the exhaustive list of possible settings that an application may have available to change through other means.  The preferences property list will naturally allow more granular control than AppleScript.  The `settings set` only contains a few of the possible settings.  So are you wishing to iterate over properties in the `current settings of xtab`, or iterate over property list keys pertaining to that tab's profile ?

Comment: @CJK then how does changing one settings set to another change the app settings that the script doesn't have access to? Also if true then how would one edit the plist without reboot with a non hard coded path to the file?

Comment: Applying a `settings set` in AppleScript sends an Apple event to the application, which contains the data affected by properties available for us to set in our script, but it may also contains other information that isn't made available to us.  Additionally, once the Apple event is received by Terminal, it triggers a function call that actually applies the settings.  It's most likely at this point that it ensures all possible settings are applied and stored, not just the ones AppleScript knows about.